# Finding k points in a set with largest total distance (measured to nearest point in k)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

We are given a set of points $S$. Given $K$ is any subset of size $k$, how do I efficiently find the following:

$\mathop{\arg\max}\limits_K$
$\sum_{x_i\in K} \mathop{\min}\limits_{x_j \in K, x_j \ne x_i}d(x_i,x_j)$

Comment: Would initializing a set N as {}, looping while |N|<k, finding the xi,xj that minimize d(xi,xj) where at least one of xi,xj is not in N, and unioning N and {xi,xj} give you what you want? Other than special handling if |N| = k-1, |N union {xi,xj}| = k+1?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried so far?  If you computed the distance between every pair of points, can you reduce this to a graph-theoretic problem?  What's the context in which you encountered this problem?  Is this from an algorithms course or textbook?  Can you describe what topic you're currently studying and credit the source of the problem?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @d-w It's for my own research so not sure how much of those questions apply. The source of the problem is my brain!  I want to discover a set of maximally unique points - where each points uniqueness is defined as its distance to its nearest neighbor. Don't have any ideas for the problem beyond the obvious exhaustive or greedy approaches.

Comment: @Accumulation I don't think a greedy solution like this would be optimal

Comment: @CVDH It doesn't matter where the question comes from, we just don't like answering questions without work shown on them, mostly because it often only becomes clear what the _actual question_ is after we've seen your approach. Therefore, I suggest you try to solve this by yourself first and then explain how/where you get stuck.

Comment: @Discretelizard It's possible to provide ideas or direction without explicitly solving the question.

Comment: @CVDH Of course, but this isn't the place for that. This isn't a discussion forum. Here, we want clear questions with objective answers.

Comment: @Discretelizard I'm pretty confused about what the problem is. I have a clear question, but obviously I don't have the answer, otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. If you're suggesting I should show my "attempts" at a solution, I would say the *vast* majority of questions here don't seem to do that

Comment: @CVDH The problem is as follows: although the statement seems precise, the exact meaning of the claim is unclear as it _lacks context_. Hence, no one is sure what precisely is best to do here. Therefore, there are multiple suggestions that have been made here that you can consider. If those suggestions are inadequate (it is likely that they are), you editing the question to mention why they are would help us to determine a context for the question. 

Finally, it is likely there is some 'hidden' context here: why have you used the graphs tag? A graph is something quite different from a set.

Comment: @Discretelizard I used the graph tag because the question only requires a set of points, and the distances between them -- the problem can equivalently be described as picking a set of nodes from a fully-connected graph.  Otherwise, I think the question is very plainly stated, so I'm not sure what is needed as "context" beyond what's already here.